# Find item in an array that matches any item in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Let's say I have an array of strings

```
words = ["quick", "brown", "fox"]
```

and another array of strings

```
animals = ["rabbit", "fox", "squirrel"]
```

I'm looking for a function that will return the index of any matches in `words`. Something like this:

`words.findMatches(animals) // returns 2, the index at which "fox" occurs`

Comment: What happens if there is more than one match? Should give you the match in animals (which makes the index 1) or the index in words ?

Comment: What if there is more than one match? What if there are no matches? Will both arrays always be an equal length?

Comment: You should show what you've tried already. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check http://underscorejs.org/ for something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to tetta's answer - I simply filtered out the non matches (`-1`) so the returned array contains only matching indexes.

```
var words = ["quick", "brown", "fox"];
var animals = ["rabbit", "fox", "squirrel"];

function getMatches(array1, array2) {
  var result = array1.map(function (el) {
    return array2.indexOf(el);
  });

  result.filter(function (el) {
    return el !== -1
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(getMatches(animals, words));
```

The same can be accomplished chaining the array methods:

```
function getMatches(array1, array2) {
  return array1.map(function (el) {
    return array2.indexOf(el);
  }).filter(function (el) {
    return el !== -1
  });
}

console.log(getMatches(animals, words));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. It will output [-1, 2, -1]. You can use it as you want.

```js
var words = ["quick", "brown", "fox"];
var animals = ["rabbit", "fox", "squirrel"];

function getMatches(array1, array2) {
  return array1.map(function (el) {
    return array2.indexOf(el);
  });
}

console.log(getMatches(animals, words));
```